# Why could this spammy edit be approved?

Tags: discussion, edits

I saw [this weird edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34704998/3) by a new user (rep <100), which made it to my list of questions.

My question is, why could that be approved in the first place, since it is obviously not a good edit? Was it approved by the OP for some weird reason?

EDIT: Apparently the edit was indeed made by OP himself, and so that answers why the edit went through. As in what we should do in this case, see the other question of which this question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you have a button that says "That solved my problem!" if a candidate duplicate is presented.

Comment: It is, and it allows you to "accept" that duplicate, instantly marking your question as such, afaik.

Comment: Actually my question was because I didn't realize it was made by OP, and therefore asked "Why could this edit be approved?". I don't think that is a duplicate of the proposed question, but I guess this makes my question invalid, since it was due to my mistake.

Comment: I thought that dupe applied because after all is said and done your question boils down to "Why did OP make this edit and what can I do about it?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP made that edit himself.
Apparently, he wanted to get rid of his question once he got his answer.

Rolling it back was the correct course of action, and you might want to request (warn) the OP not to do that, as well.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I didn't realize it was made by OP himself.